# InconsistentMigrationHistory error with custom django user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am creating a custom user model.

I ran the command `python manage.py makemigrations accounts` and then ran `python manage.py migrate accounts` which outputs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 86, in handle
    executor.loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 292, in check_consistent_history
    connection.alias,
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

Here is my user model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, 
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin
)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email.")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            username,
            password
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "password"]

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

Here is the only migration file in the app:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)),
                ('username', models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)),
                ('avatar', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=b'')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

I have never encountered this error before and don't know how to progress. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Seems like you changed the user model after applying the admin migrations. Please read [Changing to a custom user model mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).

Answer (score 6):

I did exactly the same thing when creating a new project in Django, what I had to do was delete the database and run the python command `manage.py migrate`. Was created the .0001_initial of the app that had the new user table and when the migrations were executed this order was seen

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, subscription
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying subscription.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

As you see `admin.0001_initial` is executed after the `subscription.0001_initial` migration, which eliminates the dependency problem

Comment: perfect answer! Solved my one!

Answer (score 2):

Django migration can have its dependencies on other Django model migrations
for instance:

```
dependencies = [
    ('language', '0001_initial'),
]
```

> Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency
>   accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'.

It seems somehow your admin.0001_initial has dependencies on accounts.0001_initial and it is already migrated. You should rework dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

It just need to include "AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.Account'" in settings after makemigrations & migrate command